# Compare two df column names and select columns in common

Tags: python, dataframe, multiple-columns

Im trying to append the `dictionary_of_columns` with the columns that two df has in common.

my Code:

```
list_of_columns = []
for column in dfUpdates.schema:
    list_of_columns.append(column.jsonValue()["name"].upper())

dictionary_of_columns = {}
dictionary_of_columns['BK_COLUMNS'] = []
dictionary_of_columns['COLUMNS'] = []
for row in df_metadata.dropDuplicates(['COLUMN_NAME', 'KeyType']).collect():
    if row.KeyType == 'PRIMARY KEY' and row.COLUMN_NAME.upper() in list_of_columns:
        dictionary_of_columns['BK_COLUMNS'].append(row.COLUMN_NAME.upper())
    elif row.KeyType  != 'PRIMARY KEY' and row.COLUMN_NAME.upper() in list_of_columns:
        dictionary_of_columns['COLUMNS'].append(row.COLUMN_NAME.upper())
```

but when I it does not match. `dict_of_columns` has more columns in it.

UPDATE:

dfupdate: column names [image]

df_metadata: values in COLUMN_NAME [image]

Desired output of `dictionary_of_columns = {}` should be: `{'BK_COLUMNS': ['CODE'],'COLUMNS':'DESCRIPTION'}`

Comment: Can you provide both sample of `dfUpdates` and `df_metadata` as Pandas dataframe and give the expected result please?

Comment: Im working in databricks and I do not use pandas, but will update my post with df sample

Comment: @Corralien i updated my post. sorry for delay

Comment: What is `BK` in `BK_COLUMNS`, and why `dictionary_of_columns['COLUMNS']` is a list but the output is just a string `'COLUMNS':'DESCRIPTION'`?

Comment: `bk` is `business key`

Answer (score 0):

The pseudocode will look like this. I create sets as the columns in the two dataframes, and then just take out the elements they have in common.

You can adapt it to suit your needs since I see you also filter primary keys.

```py
dfUpdates_cols = set(dfUpdates.columns)
df_metadata_cols = set(df_metadata.columns)

print(dfUpdates_cols & df_metadata_cols)
```

Comment: this wont work for, please take a look at my updated post